# Google Trends in R

Tags: r

I am trying to import Google Trend results into R.

I have tried [rGtrends](https://github.com/emhart/rGtrends) and [RGoogleTrends](https://github.com/omegahat/RGoogleTrends). The first seems to get stuck downloading the CSV file:

```
> require(devtools)
> install_github("rGtrends","emhart") 
> library(rGtrends)
> my_terms <- c("Twitter", "Myspace") 
> twit_ms <- rGtrends(my_terms) 
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.0/rGtrends/src/pyGTrends.py", line 105, in csv
raise Exception("Could not find requested section")
```

The second I having problems with signing in (not sure why I need to give my google username and password anyway? I can explore google trends in my browswer without doing so.)

Comment: As a warning, please stop using trivial edits to "bump" your question. If you do this again, I will lock the question.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an R issue.

A quick read of the comments section on the [pyGTrends home page](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/programmatic-google-trends-api/) and of the [issues section of rGTrends](https://github.com/emhart/rGtrends/issues/2) reveals an ongoing listing of various causes for this type of behavior and it seems that the main culprit is authentication changes with google trends.  ie: Sometimes pyGTrends works for some with 2 factor authentication, and other times for others it doesn't; sometimes the user needs to set a cookie and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work with the most current Google trend data format.

```
require(devtools) 
install_github('googletrend','okugami79')

library(googletrend) 

# You need to Login http://google.com/trends on your browser!! 

x<- gettrend(keyword='Twitter')
```